# Android: Class and Method showing strikethrough

Tags: android, android-studio

I am new to android and I am trying to connect to internet through AsyncTask class. When i am creating the class the methods to be implements have strikethough on them like this:

[image: This]

Can anyone tell me why the method and class are shown like this? And what to do about it.

Comment: This means that this class is deprecated. See the docs here - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask

Answer (score 0):

AsyncTask Api is deprecated in Android 11.
An alternative to it is to use java.util.concurrent instead..

Here's how you can do instead of AsyncTask:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

    executor.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            //Background work here

            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //UI Thread work here
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: It is showing many error. i have imported everything needed but on "executor.execute(new Runnable() { " it is showing error on execute saying "cannot resolve symbol 'execute'"

Comment: ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(); Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
Add this before  the executor.execute(new Runnable)